# How to use for .. of and Object.entries together in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'd like to create a function to filter objects using a `for .. of` statement and `Object.entries`.

I wrote the code as follows, but in object[key] I get the following error:

```
const person = {
  name: 'Jackson',
  age: 19
};

const filter = {
  age: 20
}

func<T, K extends T>(person: T, filter: K): void {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(filter)) {
    if (person[key] !== value) { // <-- ERROR
      console.log('The person you want doesn\'t exist.');
    }
  }
}

ERROR: Error:(36, 11) TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'unknown'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'unknown'.
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Your code has syntax errors. Can't execute. Please make it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that typescript doesn't know what the type of 'T' can be indexed by, if it can be. So you need to specific that T has to be some object that can be referenced, such as

`const func = <T extends Record<string, unknown>, K extends T>(...) => { ... }`.

This will make typescript happy and will ensure you cant call something like `func(1, 2)`.

Answer (score 0):

the key of K is a part of T, so you can try this

```
interface Iperson {
  [p: string]: any
}


type GetType = {
  [k in keyof Partial<Iperson>]: any;
}; // just made this type part of Iperson

function func<T extends Iperson, K extends GetType>(person: T, filter: K): void {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(filter)) {
    if (person[key] !== value) { 
      console.log('The person you want doesn\'t exist.');
    }
  }
}

const person = {
  name: 'Jackson',
  age: 19
};

const filter = {
  age: 20
}

func(person, filter)
```